# Can we display Hyperlink from Javascript alert on ASP.NET Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have the following text that needs to be displayed from Javascript ALert.

I am wondering if we can display the hyperlink from the alert itself?

```
alert('User already exists in the system, please <a href='../Login.aspx'>login</a>');
```

Appreciate your responses

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link in Javascript alert](/q/1733410/90527)

Answer (score 5):

No. You will have to make your own dialog if you want to do so (just make a modal dialog which should be pretty easy to do).
 
The alert box itself is just a simple text box.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one hyperlink, why not tie it to the OK button?

```
var answer = confirm("Flash Update Required. To get the latest version of Flash click ok.")

if (answer) {window.location = "http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/";}
else {}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the previous poster states, no.

You can have a div that you display with the message though. You could try something like this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function show(message) {
    document.getElementById('messageboxframe').innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementById('messageboxframe').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('messageboxoverlay').style.display = 'block';
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById('messageboxframe').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('messageboxoverlay').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body, div
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.messageboxoverlay
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:0.75;
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}

.messageboxviewer
{
    position: fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 200px;
    left: 40%;
    top: 30%;
    background-color: White;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>    

<body>
  <div class="messageboxoverlay" style="display:none" id="messageboxoverlay" >
  </div>
  <div class="messageboxviewer" style="display:none" id="messageboxframe" onclick="hide()">
    <span id="messagebox" />
  </div>
  <div style="margin: 5px 5px;">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="show('hello')">show messagebox</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the messageboxviewer div, you can write "whatever you want". Or you could do as the example and display a message from a function.